# Format datetime values in pandas by stripping

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a `df['timestamp']` column which has values in format: `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ`. The dtype is object.

Now, I want to split the value into 3 new columns, 1 for day, 1 for day index(mon,tues,wed,..) and 1 for hour like this:

```
Current:column=timestamp
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ

Desried:
New Col1|New Col2|New Col3
dd|hh|day_index
```

What function should I use?

Comment: Please post a sample of your dataframe, that will make it easy to run the codes. You can paste the dataframe from excel of CSV into the question inside the 'HTML Snippet' (the icon next to picture icon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said column `timestamp` is of type `object`, I assume it's `string`. Since the format is fixed, use `str.slice` to get corresponding chars. To get the week days, use `dt.day_name()` on `datetime64`, which is converted from `timestamp`.

```
data = {'timestamp': ['2019-07-01T05:23:33Z', '2019-07-03T02:12:33Z', '2019-07-23T11:05:23Z', '2019-07-12T08:15:51Z'], 'Val': [1.24,1.259, 1.27,1.298] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
ds = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce')
df['datetime'] = ds
df['dd'] = df['timestamp'].str.slice(start=8, stop=10)
df['hh'] = df['timestamp'].str.slice(start=11, stop=13)
df['weekday'] = df['datetime'].dt.day_name()
print(df)
```

The output:

```
          timestamp          Val              datetime          dd  hh  weekday
0   2019-07-01T05:23:33Z    1.240   2019-07-01 05:23:33+00:00   01  05  Monday
1   2019-07-03T02:12:33Z    1.259   2019-07-03 02:12:33+00:00   03  02  Wednesday
2   2019-07-23T11:05:23Z    1.270   2019-07-23 11:05:23+00:00   23  11  Tuesday
3   2019-07-12T08:15:51Z    1.298   2019-07-12 08:15:51+00:00   12  08  Friday
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert the `df['timestamp']` column to a DateTime object. Then extract Year, Month & Day from it. Code below.

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce')
df['Year'] = df['timestamp'].dt.year
df['Month'] = df['timestamp'].dt.month
df['Day'] = df['timestamp'].dt.day
```

Comment: when I used the code and did df.dtypes, it still shows as object. why?

Comment: it should not. it is showing me as "datetime64[ns, UTC]"